# eigs routine in octave

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, finite-difference, eigenvalues, octave

I am using octave and observed a problem with the eigs-routine for non symmetric matrices. Using GNU octave version 3.8.1 the code below gives significant difference of eigenvalues although same commands are executed. The difference of eigenvalues is computed by subracting the `eig`- and `eigs`-eigenvalues.

```
% solves the Eigenvalue Problem 
%   -y''= lambda^2 y on the interval (a,b)
%
% with mixed boundary conditions
%   -- dirichlet boundary condition y(a)=0
%   -- robin boundary condition   y'(b)=y(b)
clear all;
close all;
p=6;
%% number of points
n=2^p;
%% grid space
h=1/2^p;
%% numbers of eigenvalues to find
kmax=8;
%% assemble symmetric 2nd finite difference matrix
Lh=-gallery('tridiag',n,1,-2,1)./(h^2);
%% apply robin boundary in last line
Lh(n,:)=0.0;
Lh(n,n-1)=-2/h^2;
Lh(n,n)=-1/h^2*(2*h-2);
%% options for eigs
% opts.tol=1e-10;
opts.p=max(floor(n/2),2*kmax);
comp=0;
while comp<10 % do the same thing 10 times
    %% use eig to get all eigenvalues
    [~,LambdaEig]=eig(Lh);
    if isreal(diag(LambdaEig))
      LambdaEig=sort(diag(LambdaEig));
      lambdaEig=LambdaEig(1:kmax);
    else
      warning('eigenvalues of eig are not real')
    end
    %% use eigs routine to get 1st kmax eigenvalues of smallest magnitude
    [~,LambdaEigs,fl]=eigs(Lh,kmax,'sr');
    if isreal(diag(LambdaEigs))
      LambdaEig=sort(diag(LambdaEig));
      lambdaEigs=sort(diag(LambdaEigs));
    else
      warning('eigenvalues of eigs are not real')
    end
    errmax=max(abs(lambdaEig-lambdaEigs));
    disp(['eigs flag: ' num2str(fl) ', maximum error of eigenvalues: '...
            num2str(errmax)])
    comp=comp+1;
end
```

Do you have an explanation for this? GNU octave's manual reports that `eigs` is based on the ARPACK package. I guess ARPACK is widely used for large eigenvalue problems and tested well. But GNU octave's `eigs`-routine seems not to be reliable for this problem.

I would like to use the `eigs` routine for eigenvalue computations of larger general eigenvalue problems $A x=\lambda B x$ with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2000\times2000}$ in GNU octave. Because of the matrix size Krylow subspace methods are reasonably to me and as far as I know `eigs` is a modified Arnoldi iteration.

Do you have any recommendations how to continue?

Comment: What is the actual output you are getting? Possible duplicate of http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/matlab-eigs-wrong-eigenvalues-for-tridiagonal-matrix

Comment: Here is the output

    `fl = 0
     errmax =    1.5815e+04
    fl = 0
    errmax =    1.3520e-12
    fl = 0
    errmax =    2.2737e-12
    fl = 0
    errmax =    2.7285e-12
    fl = 0
    errmax =    1.8190e-12
    fl = 0
    errmax =    1.7906e-12
    fl = 0
    errmax =    1.5818e+04
    fl = 0
    errmax =    1.5805e+04
    fl = 0
    errmax =    2.2737e-12
    fl = 0
    errmax =    1.3074e-12`

`fl` is the flag of `eigs` indicating convergence.I also saw the reference you gave. There it says that specifying the number of Lanczos vectors in `opts` is a solution. But it did not work out.

Comment: I haven't run the code, but one issue could be that you are calling `sort` on the eigenvalues, which might be complex in general since your boundary conditions create a nonsymmetric matrix. For complex numbers, `sort` defaults to ordering by nondecreasing modulus: there could be mismatches if there are eigenvalues with the same modulus (e.g., complex conjugate pairs).

Comment: Dear Federico,
thanks for your remark. I modified the code above to check if eigenvalues are real. By the way, although the matrix is not symmetric the eigenvalues are real. This is due to the fact that the analytic solution of the eigenvalue problem has real positive eigenvalues.
Regards

Comment: I experimented a bit with your code in octave 3.8.1. The fact that the results vary so widely from trial to trial is very disturbing. I modified your code slightly to print all 8 eigenvalues from both eig and eigs. Sometimes only one or two differ; sometimes all 8 are very different. I would encourage you to submit a bug report to the Octave team. (The MATLAB version of eigs doesn't exhibit this problem.)

Comment: @BillGreene You are right, this is likely a bug. Compare `for i=1:100; [V, D] = eigs(Lh, 8, 'sr'); fprintf('%f\n', norm(D, 'inf')); end` and `for i=1:100; D = eigs(Lh, 8, 'sr'); fprintf('%f\n', norm(D, 'inf')); end`, I only get bad answers with the `[V,D]` form.

Comment: @BillGreene I already submitted a [bug report](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44004) to the developers. @Kirill It is interesting that bad answers occur only if `eigs` is called with `[V,D]=eigs(...)`. I will add this to my bug report. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [submitted bug report](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44004), there was a bug in `ARPACK` < **3.1.5** regarding `dneupd`, the subroutine that "returns the converged approximations to eigenvalues". In `ARPACK` **3.2.0**, this particular issue has been resolved. Current distributions of `octave` are usually linked with a much higher version of `ARPACK`; thus, such behaviour is not expected to happen anymore. But checking that your `octave` is linked against a new (technically, I want to say *stable* version of `ARPACK`) is worth a shot.

I've tested the code above in `octave 4.2.2` with `ARPACK 3.5.0` installed using MacPorts. The results seem to be stable with a max difference in the eigenvalues between the two around `1E-12`, which is, I think, more than satisfactory.